# Display the URL of where the content is located in my search results

Tags: views, 8, search

I'm using SOLR search/search API on my Drupal 8 site and I've set the view to display the following two fields:

- Content datasource: Title *(The title & link to the page)*
- Search: Excerpt *(Highlighted text of the searched keywords found on the page)*

I would also like to display the URL of the page that the content is located below those two fields. However, there is no URL field to add. I've also tried to get just the URL from the 'Title' field, but can't seem to get it from there either.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Example of what I want search results to look like]

Would anyone have any ideas as to how to add that at all?

Comment: Add the URI to be indexed, then use that in the result output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search API provides several general fields (e.g. Aggregated field, Rendered HTML output, URI, etc.) which are available to all Datasources.

Edit your index, when on the Fields tab, click Add fields and under the General heading add URI. You will need to re-index your content and the new fields should be available.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. This worked for me.